# USB-sized board for running USB exploits

Tags: usb, microcontroller, cheap

I'm looking for a USB-sized board to build a USB exploitation tool.

I'm looking to build something similar to a [Bash Bunny](https://shop.hak5.org/products/bash-bunny) or a [Rubber Ducky](https://shop.hak5.org/collections/physical-access/products/usb-rubber-ducky-deluxe).

Requirements:

- is a pre-built board (prefered) or chip
- able to run a Linux OS (Ubuntu or Kali)
- has a USB male head and a micro-SD slot (for swapping payloads)
- WiFi with Monitor mode
- Bluetooth
- is relatively cheap (10-30 USD maybe)

I'd like to make this work with both "plug-and-go" and persistent logging. Having a lot of IO pins besides for the USB & SD card (like the [Raspberry Pi Compute Module](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/)) can make it unnecessarily complex and expensive.

Of course, it being a pre-built board where I just have to solder on a few IO pins makes it easier, but a simple and cheap processing chip is also OK.

The purpose for making this is to make it a multi-purpose tool, capable of exfiltrating data, log data persistently, sitting and gathering data about WiFi and Bluetooth devices walking around, plug-inject-go jobs, etc.

The Rubber Ducky isn't multi-purposed enough and the Bash Bunny is rather expensive. I've looked around for a few USBs and boards but have yet to found something good.

Example uses:

- Plug the USB, wait a few seconds, unplug and leave with exfiltrated data (classic rubber ducky stuff)
- Plug, inject backdoors and stuff, unplug, come back later to use the injected code
- Plug, persistently log data (eg keyboard strokes, data streams, etc), return to unplug, leave with an SD card full of logged data
- Plug, use a phone charger or PC's USB port just for power, monitor WiFi and Bluetooth in the area and log that into the USB.

I do realize that sounds like a lot to ask for of something 10-30 USD but I'm mainly looking for something that can do basic processing with USB, micro SD, WiFi and Bluetooth.

Comment: Is that a one time thing or you want to produce those in some _large_ numbers?! Have you tried to make it work with a Pi already?

Comment: This is mostly a one time project but I'd like to be able to make more of them with some ease later one. I also plan to make this an open-source project. Also, I haven't tried with it a Pi since the Pi is rather expensive with a lot of redundancy, as explained in the post. Additionally, It doesn't seem available in my area,